# What does sql status 'Queries' consist of?

Tags: mysql, database

This MySql [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Queries) mentioned in mysql client if I type

`mysql> show status Queries`

this command will display "The number of statements executed by the server. ". What does this "Queries" consist of?
When I type

`mysql> show status like COM_%`,

and sum count of COM_select, COM_update, COM_insert, COM_delete, these do not add up to status'Queries', whereas select, update, insert, delete are all the sql queries I believe.

So, what exactly is the status 'Queries' tracking? (The [document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Queries) mentioned what status 'Queries' does not consist of: "COM_PING or COM_STATISTICS", but did not mention what exactly the status 'Queries' is consist of, and why the status 'Queries' consist of these statements)

Comment: That said, I can make a guess. Stack Overflow is for questions about [specific code problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but many people would think that you didn't present any code in your question. Your question might be better suited to dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Yituo maybe this question would be better if asked on [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> select, update, insert, delete are all the sql queries I believe.

`SHOW` itself is also a statement type, and there are many other types of SQL statements: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-statements.html

You can also query command types:

```
mysql> show session status like 'Com_%';
+-------------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                       | Value |
+-------------------------------------+-------+
...
+-------------------------------------+-------+
175 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The manual explains that `Queries` counts the number of statements executed by the server, including those executed included those run within stored routines. `Questions` only includes statements executed by the client, not in stored routines. So `Queries` should be a superset of `Questions`.